# How to split a NSAttributedString into an Array of NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, string, split, nsattributedstring

I have a NSAttributedString and want to split it at every `“***“`. So in effect, I want to split a NSAttributedString everywhere where this String appeares. The result should be something like an Array of NSAttributedStrings. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to find yourself the different ranges of "***" (using the `.string` property) and use `attributedSubstringFromRange:`. There is no built in method, all manual/oldschool by redoing and `componentsSeparatedByString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this extension for  NSAttributedString

```
private extension NSAttributedString {
    func components(separatedBy separator: String) -> [NSAttributedString] {
        var result = [NSAttributedString]()
        let separatedStrings = string.components(separatedBy: separator)
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        for string in separatedStrings {
            range.length = string.count
            let attributedString = attributedSubstring(from: range)
            result.append(attributedString)
            range.location += range.length + separator.count
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Example`

```
let atributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "A***B***C***D")
let resultArray = atributedString.components(separatedBy: "***")
for atString in resultArray {
    print(atString)
}
```